# Navigation bar positioning cross compatibility

Tags: android, html, css, cross-browser

I want a navigation bar positioned on top of the viewport, aligned to the right with my content.

I figured this out using various sources, put up a minimal working example at https://jsfiddle.net/EAEKc/1657/.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Some text in the wrapper
    <div class="nav-container">
        <nav class="site-nav"> 
            <a class="link">Link1</a>
            <a class="link">Link2</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Hello content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
.nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
    max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.site-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #00F;
}
.link {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.content {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #A00;
}
```

As mentioned, this "works for me" (Current Firefox @Desktop, Safari @iOS, Firefox @Android), but it doesn't seem too cross-browser-compatible: My Android-builtin browser still likes to align the bar to the left. Or worse, just kicks it slightly off-screen to the left.

How would one begin to make this work for most browsers?

### Solution

Combining hints from multiple resources, I was able to come up with a much simpler solution. Check https://jsfiddle.net/EAEKc/1668/ for a demonstration.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Some text in the wrapper
    <div class="nav-outer-container">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="site-nav"> 
                <a class="link">Link1</a>
                <a class="link">Link2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Hello content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (only differing parts)

```
.nav-outer-container{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-align: right;
}
.site-nav {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #00F;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`calc()` is not compatible with all browsers see here for a list of desk top and mobile compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

For all un compatible versions you should have a fallback, the link I gave you has examples of the fall backs too.

Comment: Thanks to your entry point, I managed to get rid of most `calc()` statements in my code, so no crucial `calc`s left, which gained my page a lot of responsiveness! Regards!